# Enable two crosshairs on subsequent mouse selections

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am working with JFreeChart in my Java application, and I have successfully implemented a chart with multiple axes. I have enabled crosshairs for both the domain and range axes using the following code:

```
this.plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
this.plot.setDomainCrosshairLockedOnData(true);
this.plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
this.plot.setRangeCrosshairLockedOnData(true);
```

This configuration displays a crosshair on mouse selection, providing valuable information about data points. However, my requirement is to enable two crosshairs on subsequent mouse selections. I would like to have the ability to see two crosshairs simultaneously, each responding to its own mouse selection.

If anyone has experience with implementing multiple crosshairs in JFreeChart or has suggestions on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your insights or example code snippets.

[image]

Comment: How would two crosshairs work?  When you click on the chart with the mouse, how would the two crosshairs decide which crosshair responds to the mouse click?

Comment: Also consider a `Marker` or `Annotation` in response to the mouse event.

Comment: I would like the second crosshair to appear on the next mouse click. This way, the first crosshair remains visible, and with each subsequent mouse click, a new crosshair is added. This allows me to see both the previous crosshair and the current one, providing a layered representation of crosshair positions.

Comment: You might look among the [sample charts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) to see which approach you want.